# jQuery UI: pass id of element dragged and dropped to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a function called saveSmilies which accepts two parameters: the dragged element id and the dropped element id.

I'm trying to do this like:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
                    revert: true,
                    drop: function() {
                        $dropped = $(this);
                    },
                    stop: function() {
                        quiz1.saveSmilies($(this).attr('id'), $dropped);
                    }
                });
```

But it doesn't work... Am I doing this completely wrong? Or just a typo somewhere?

So basically If I dragged an element with an id of 'box1' and dropped it on an element with an id of 'box2' then it would do the following: `quiz1.saveSmilies('box1','box2');`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Id of BOTH draggable and droppable ID's jqueryUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668796/need-id-of-both-draggable-and-droppable-ids-jqueryui)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
drop: function(ev, ui) {
    var draggedID = ui.draggable.attr("id");
    var droppedID = $(this).attr("id");
}
```